# iOS 11 Statusbar overlaps Webapp after changing orientation

Tags: iphone, web-applications, orientation, ios11, statusbar

With the recent update to iOS11 we came to following issue with our Webapps after using Safari's "Add to homescreen".

When opening the Webapp, the behaviour of the status bar is as wanted (The statusbar is on top and the Webapp is displayed right under the status bar). After changing the orientation, the status bar acts not as it should.

We tried different meta tags but nothing seems to work.

Did anyone find a fix for it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Example link:
https://awf.marketing/app/store/zihler

(to recreate the issue - needs to opened with an iPhone running iOS11+)

Images:

[1. Normal view of the Webapp after opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f693h.jpg)

[2. After switching to "Landscape" then back to "Portrait" the Webapp content gets placed behind the status bar instead of under it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lKND.jpg)

Comment: The issue got fixed in the iOS 11.3 developer Beta. We hope it will apply to the official update.